# Rendered image is not as detailed as in rendered view

Tags: rendering, error

[image: The top image is the rendered view of the camera and the bottom picture is the fully rendered scene.]

Does anyone know why the top is so low quality compared to the actually rendered image. The plane has True displacement enabled. Does anyone know the problem, if you need further more details I can give them.

Comment: Look at the subsurf modifier, make sure that you have the same number of subdivisions for rendering than you do for preview.

Comment: may be you should decrese the dicing rate

Answer (score 1):

It is from your subserf modifier. If your using the experimental or adaptive, make sure both values from the view and render are the same, i.e. the Dicing Rate must be 1 and the levels must be proportional to it.

And also the view angel will affect your render in adaptive subserf. Objects at the far will have less subdivision than those from the front, i.e, if your camera is pointing at the front and you are looking at the back, there will be a noticeable difference.